# How can I reverse code around an equal sign in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

After writing code to populate textboxes from an object, such as:

```
txtFirstName.Text = customer.FirstName;
txtLastName.Text = customer.LastName;
txtAddress.Text = customer.Address;
txtCity.Text = customer.City;
```

is there way in Visual Studio (or even something like Resharper) to copy and paste this code into a save function and reverse the code around the equal sign, so that it will look like:

```
customer.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
customer.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
customer.Address = txtAddress.Text;
customer.City = txtCity.Text;
```

Comment: See also my approach with an AutoHotkey script https://stackoverflow.com/a/60452617/1265105

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Before VS2012:

- Copy and paste the original block of code
- Select it again in the place you want to switch
- Press Ctrl-H to get the "Replace" box up
- Under "Find what" put: `{[a-zA-Z\.]*} = {[a-zA-Z\.]*};`
- Under "Replace with" put: `\2 = \1;`
- Look in: "Selection"
- Use: "Regular expressions"
- Hit Replace All

With VS2012 (and presumably later) which uses .NET regular expressions:

- Copy and paste the original block of code
- Select it again in the place you want to switch
- Press Ctrl-H to get the "Replace" box up
- Under "Find what" put: `([a-zA-Z\.]*) = ([a-zA-Z\.]*);`
- Under "Replace with" put: `${2} = ${1};`
- Make sure that the `.*` (regular expressions) icon is selected (the third one along under the replacement textbox)
- Hit Replace All

Comment: This one works for variable names with numbers.  
([\w\.]+) = ([\w\.]+);

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in either vs2017 or vs2019. I always get not found errors.

Comment: @Louis: Can you give a concrete example of the text you'd expect to be found, so we can try to reproduce that? I don't see any reason it wouldn't work as written, unless (for example) you don't have spaces around your `=` sign.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I just tried to do the same task as the OP. Your solution seems straightforward. I'm just not sure why not working in vs2019. For the time being, I use Resharper and it has worked pretty well.

Comment: @Louis: Again, without a *really concrete example*, it's hard to help you. I could try doing it myself with an example, find it works, and then be in no better position to help you, having wasted my time. If you provide a concrete example, I won't waste my time, and you'll get an answer sooner.

Answer (score 4):

None that I know of. Of course, if you use one of the many binding approaches available, then you won't have to - the binding will do the update in both directions (including change via notifications).

So for winforms:

```
txtFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", customer, "FirstName");
```

etc

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need but I had to accept more characters than `a-zA-Z\.` in the solution provided by John so I slightly modified its regular exception like this :

Find what : `{^[^\=]*} = {.*}`

Replace with :  `\2 = \1`

This will reverse **anything** arround the **first equal sign** found on a line

Answer (score 1):

The *Search term* RegEx that worked for me:

Search
`([^= ]*) = ([^= ]*);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 for programming in C# and I find the way out to achieve the flip with the following modifications:

Find: `([a-zA-Z1-9-+()<>\.]*) = ([a-zA-Z1-9-+()<>\.]*)`

Replace: `${2} = ${1}`

Maybe it can help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

An option to get them in there that way in the first place with Resharper would be to define a live template similar to:

```
$uiElement$ = $dto$;
$dto$ = $uiElement$;
```

This will allow you to type them once and it will duplicate it for you and then you can cut and paste the save version to the other method.

Answer (score 0):

Dead thread, but arrived here so I thought I would add that ReSharper has added this as of ~2016 as it is a fairly common add-on.

Source: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206688445-Reversing-Assignments

TL;DR. If you have ReSharper, highlight the block and use resharper context menu to "Reverse Assignments". OR, line by line you can use ctrl + shift + alt + arrow to move it left or right depending on which side of the = your cursor is on.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted answer but it didn't work for me on VS2022. So I searched and found this tool which helped me a lot.
After installing, you need to select your code and ask for ***Refactoring -> Invert assignment***.

[Assignment Invertor on VS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NeVeS.InvertAssignmentDirection)

Answer (score 0):

This pattern worked for me in Visual Studio 2019:

In Visual Studio 2019:

1. Search and replace (ctrl + f)
2. Select the regex pattern (".*")
3. Select the "selection" option from the drop
   down.
4. Select the code you want to swap.

**The pattern to use:**

Find what: `([^= ]*) = ([^= ]*);`

Replace with: `${2} = ${1};`

Hit replace all.