# Does anyone know a visual studio keyboard short cut to swap around two sides of a statement?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Just wondering if anyone knows the keyboard shortcut to swap around two sides of a statement. For example:

I want to swap

```csh
firstNameTextbox.Text = myData.FirstName;
```

to

```csh
myData.FirstName = firstNameTextbox.Text;
```

Does anyone know the shortcut, if there is one? Obviously I would type them out, but there is **a lot** of statements I need to swap, and I think a shortcut like that would be useful!

Feel free to throw in any shortcuts you think are cool!

My contribution would be <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> - this will format your code to Visual Studio standards! Pretty well known I'm guessing but I use it **all** the time! :)

**UPDATE**

Just to let everyone know, using a bit of snooping of the article that was posted, I managed to construct a regular expression, so here it is:

Find:

```csh
{.+\.Text = myData\..+};
```

And replace with:

```csh
\2 = \1;
```

Hopefully people can apply this to their own expressions they want to swap!

Comment: sorry bro but u mistyped it - the shortcut to format your code to Visual studio standards is --->>>> "CTRL + K, D"

Comment: @J Sinh: I'm not a 'bro', and I didn't mistype it, this is the keyboard shortcut. Try it.

Comment: configure an external tool command "open emacs", then do a keyboard macro with C-x-(-C-s=C-space-end-C-x-home-C-y-C-x-) then enjoy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following thread is a good place to begin with

[Invert assignment direction in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012807/invert-assignment-direction-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would go about doing that without a specific keyboard shortcut:

- First, select the text you want to modify and replace

  ```
  " = " with "                 =               "
  ```

  (the key here is to add a lot of spaces).
- If you hold down `Alt` and use the mouse, you can select a "block" of code.  Use this to select only the text on the right side of the equation (it's helpful to add extra white space here in your selection)
- Use the same `Alt` + `Left-Click` combination to select the beginning of the left side (just select a blank area).  You should be able to paste text into here.
- If you added extra white space to the text you just added, just should be able to easily insert an `=` using the `Alt` + `Click` technique.  Use the same trick to remove the equal sign that's dangling on the right side of your code block.

While this might not do *exactly* what you're looking for, I've found these tricks quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), you can do this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>

Comment: That shortcut moves the whole line rather than swapping the LHS and RHS of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

The feature is in Resharper. Select the code segment and  click the content wizard, which is a pencil icon in the left corner reading *View Actions List*, then choose *Reverse Assignment*.
It is done.

Comment: Its now the Hammer in the left hand gutter

Answer (score 0):

[swap-word](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davidmart.swap-word#overview) is a VSCode extension which sounds like it would do what you want.

> Quickly swap places two words or selections...

But I'm not sure if it is compatible with VS.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was not happy with the answers where I need to enter complicated strings into the Visual Studio search/replace dialog, I wrote myself a little [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script, that performs the swaps with only the need to press a keyboard shortcut. And this, no matter if you are in VS or in another IDE.
This hotkey (start it once simply from a textfile as script or compiled to exe) runs whenever *Win+Ctrl-S* is pressed

```
#^s Up::  
 clipboard := "" ; Empty the clipboard
 Sendinput {Ctrl down}c{ctrl up}
 Clipwait
 Loop, Parse, clipboard, `n, `r  ; iterates over seperates lines
 {   
  array := StrSplit(RegExReplace(A_LoopField,";",""),"=")  ; remove semicolon and split by '='
  SendInput, % Trim(array[2]) . " = " .  Trim(array[1]) . ";{Enter}"
 }
return
```

Many more details are possible, e.g. also supporting code where lines end with a comma

...**and** I can put many more hotkeys and hotstrings into the same script, e.g. for my most mistyped words:

```
::esle::else    ; this 1 line rewrites all my 'else' typos
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the find-replace option in Visual Studio. IMHO the REGEX string is not that complicated, and moreover, you don't need to understand the expression in order to use it.
The following regex string works for most programming languages:

```
([\w\.]+)\s*=\s*([\w\.]+)
```

For Visual Studio's you want to use $ argument in the replace text.

```
$2 = $1
```

Make sure to enable regex.

[image]

To do this in one shot, you can select a section of the document, and click the replace-all option.

- **Before:**

  ```
   comboBoxAddOriginalSrcTextToComment.SelectedIndex = Settings.Default.comboBoxAddOriginalSrcTextToComment;
   comboBoxDefaultLanguageSet.SelectedIndex = Settings.Default.comboBoxDefaultLanguageSet;
   comboBoxItemsPerTransaltionRequest.SelectedIndex = Settings.Default.comboBoxItemsPerTransaltionRequest;
   comboBoxLogFileVerbosityLevel.SelectedIndex = Settings.Default.comboBoxLogFileVerbosityLevel;
   comboBoxScreenVerbosityLevel.SelectedIndex = Settings.Default.comboBoxScreenVerbosityLevel;
  ```
- **After:**

  ```
   Settings.Default.comboBoxAddOriginalSrcTextToComment = comboBoxAddOriginalSrcTextToComment.SelectedIndex;
   Settings.Default.comboBoxDefaultLanguageSet = comboBoxDefaultLanguageSet.SelectedIndex;
   Settings.Default.comboBoxItemsPerTransaltionRequest = comboBoxItemsPerTransaltionRequest.SelectedIndex;
   Settings.Default.comboBoxLogFileVerbosityLevel = comboBoxLogFileVerbosityLevel.SelectedIndex;
   Settings.Default.comboBoxScreenVerbosityLevel = comboBoxScreenVerbosityLevel.SelectedIndex;
  ```

##### IMHO: It's better for a developer to learn to use the IDE (Integrated Development Environment), then to create new tools to do the same thing the IDE can do.

Comment: Does not work if parentheses are involved. A bit made up example:
`sfdXml.InitialDirectory(1).Ex = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments).Fx`
  

`([\w\.\(\)]+)\s*=\s*([\w\.\(\)]+)` works better with parentheses.

Regarding the IDE, it switches back to the whole document as fast as possible, and it does not save the patterns between restarts. (VS 2022) The good old Delphi 7 IDE + GExperts is still more productive.