# Swap text blocks in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any built-in way to **swap two arbitrary text blocks in Visual Studio**? (I happen to be using VS2015).

Example: you have a method such as `FooBar(target, source)` and you decide it would make more sense to be `FooBar(source, target)`. If you've called `FooBar` in a lot of places you might need to run multiple operations to swap the various pairs of variable names.

Having this done also within comments could also be useful.

While obviously you could do this with multiple search & replaces, or multiple Edit->Refactor->Renames (^R^R), those approaches are somewhat prone to error, and are more tedious.

---

If this doesn't actually exist within Visual Studio but another tool like Notepad++ (for instance) has this capability, that is almost as good.

---

These questions are similar but for more specific scenarios:

- [Does anyone know a visual studio keyboard short cut to swap around two sides of a statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759997/does-anyone-know-a-visual-studio-keyboard-short-cut-to-swap-around-two-sides-of)
- [Invert assignment direction in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012807/invert-assignment-direction-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Are 3 renames that bad?

Comment: ReSharper will do this for you, if you have that, that is, it will allow you to change the signature of a method, changing the positions of the parameters and updating all calls to the method to adjust.

Comment: @user202729 it could be many more than that. You'd have to rename the parameters, and then also any arguments in any context where the method is called. It adds up. This seems like a perfect task for a computer to do :)

Comment: Visual Studio can reorder parameters by default. `Edit > Refactor > Reorder Parameters...` will change the order automatically in all places which call the function.

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit that's maybe not a "perfect" solution but it covers a lot of the cases I was thinking of. You should add that as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has the built in functionality to reorder parameters. You can select this by using `Edit > Refactor > Reorder Parameters...`. Changing parameters in this form will update all the method calls in addition to the method. You can also request to preview all the changes which will be made.

[More information here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ss5z206.aspx)