# Is it possible to create a Regex Macro and tie it to a hotkey

Tags: visual-studio-2013, macros, hotkeys

Found this awesome swap code from 1 side of the equal sign to the other using  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430145/how-can-i-reverse-code-around-an-equal-sign-in-visual-studio)

For ease here is the image of what I would like to turn into a hotkey:

[image]

Is it possible to turn this into a macro + hotkey in Visual Studio 2013 for non macro keyboards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Macros for Visual Studio 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d3fbf133-e51b-41a2-b86f-9560a96ff62b) and [Visual Commander](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/deda8ac1-75e6-4068-89ab-b607cee38f2d) let you record a macro and assign a shortcut to it.